# android json data retrieving

Tags: android, json

I am new to Json. I want to retrieve the distance between two places using json. I want to get "text"(Distance b/w two places) from "distance" object which is in "legs" array which in turn is in "routes" array.
Link(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Adoor&destination=Thiruvananthapuram%20Zoo&sensor=false)

Java code:

```
 String uri="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+destination+"&destination="+tour_place+"&sensor=false";
            queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
            JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                         JSONArray array=response.getJSONArray("legs");
                 distances.add(array.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance").getDouble("text"));


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                }
            });
                queue.add(objectRequest);
```

Comment: If you are new you should first study about json objects and json arrays and how to parse json in android

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ read this tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, will now post the code I did. Try this out.

```
try {
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jStr);
            JSONArray jaRoutes = json.getJSONArray("routes");
            JSONArray jaLegs = jaRoutes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs");
            JSONObject joDistance = jaLegs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance");
            String text = joDistance.getString("text");
            Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d("SAMPLE", e.toString());
        }
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: @jobin saw your question regarding bounds in the other answer, will just reply here to avoid long comments discussion. Routes is a JSONArray (hence the [ ] tags) which means it consists of multiple JSONObjects ( { } tags). bounds is still in the JSONObject in index 0, with the key "bounds"

It's easier if you look at it in an editor. You can try it out here [link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/). Just paste the JSON string in there. It'll appear in a *prettier* way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
try{

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thewholething.toString());
JSONArray routes =object.getJSONArray("routes");
JSONArray legs=routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs")
JSONObject distance =legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance");
String text=distance.getString("text");

}
 catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now the String text contains your value.

Comment: JSONArray legs =routes.etJSONArray("legs");It shows getJSONArray(int index)

Comment: it was not "et", it was "get". My typing  mistake. Sorry. Try it now. I have edited the answer. :)

Comment: For JSONArrays, you should iterate through them (if there are multiple values) but seeing as there is only one, and if you only need that specific one, you can just go ahead and replace it with something like this -- 
***legs = routes.getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray("legs");***

Keeping in mind the pattern.. Routes(Array) --> Get index 0 to get first JSONObject that contains the key ***legs*** which is a JSONArray.. Hence the index first, then the key after.

Comment: @sept   routes.getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray("legs");It shows routes.getJSONArray(0).getJSONArray(int index)

Comment: you can use **routes.getJsonArray("legs");** for getting legs array from there you can loop for internal data..

Comment: @malli It still shows int as argument in routes.getJSONArray()

Comment: bounds is at index 0 and legs is at index 1 inside routes. So you can use JSONArray legs =routes.getJSONArray(1) instead of routes.getJSONArray("legs").

Comment: JSONArray routes=response.getJSONArray("routes");
                  JSONArray legs=routes.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("legs");
                    JSONObject distance=legs.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("distance");
                    distance1=distance.getString("text");

Comment: use this `JSONArray routes=response.getJSONArray("routes"); JSONArray legs=routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs")` instead of `JSONArray routes=response.getJSONArray("routes"); JSONArray legs=routes.getJSONObject(1).getJSONArray("legs")`

Comment: legs=routes.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("legs") is right

Comment: @jobin already posted an answer as to avoid long discussion in comments. Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: @malli.It worked.Thank you.But I have a question.If the position of legs is 0,then what is the position of "bounds" in routes

Comment: 0 is not a legs position.we are retrieving 0th object from routes array.if you want to parse bounds just use `routes.getJsonObject(0).getJsonObject("bounds");`

Answer (score 0):

From your response, you parse your routes array first.

```
JsonArray routes = response.getJsonArray("routes");
```

From here, you can get legs array like the following.

```
JsonArray legs = routes.getJsonArray("legs");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = new ArrayList<List<HashMap<String,String>>>() ;
        JSONArray jRoutes = null;
        JSONArray jLegs = null;
        JSONArray jSteps = null;
        JSONObject jDistance = null;
        JSONObject jDuration = null;

        try {

            jRoutes = jObject.getJSONArray("routes");

            /** Traversing all routes */
            for(int i=0;i<jRoutes.length();i++){
                jLegs = ( (JSONObject)jRoutes.get(i)).getJSONArray("legs");

                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

                /** Traversing all legs */
                for(int j=0;j<jLegs.length();j++){

                    /** Getting distance from the json data */
                    jDistance = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDistance = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDistance.put("distance", jDistance.getString("text"));

                    /** Getting duration from the json data */
                    jDuration = ((JSONObject) jLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                    HashMap<String, String> hmDuration = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hmDuration.put("duration", jDuration.getString("text"));

                    /** Adding distance object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDistance);

                    /** Adding duration object to the path */
                    path.add(hmDuration);

                    jSteps = ( (JSONObject)jLegs.get(j)).getJSONArray("steps");

                    /** Traversing all steps */
                    for(int k=0;k<jSteps.length();k++){
                        String polyline = "";
                        polyline = (String)((JSONObject)((JSONObject)jSteps.get(k)).get("polyline")).get("points");
                        List<LatLng> list = decodePoly(polyline);

                        /** Traversing all points */
                        for(int l=0;l<list.size();l++){
                            HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            hm.put("lat", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).latitude) );
                            hm.put("lng", Double.toString(((LatLng)list.get(l)).longitude) );
                            path.add(hm);
                        }
                    }
                }
                routes.add(path);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
 try {
              StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, uri, (String) null,  new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    ;
                    Log.d("", ".......response====" + response.toString());

                    ////////
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                        if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {

                        }
                        if (serverCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                            try {

                                if ("1".equals(serverCode))
                                {
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("routes");
                                 if(jsonArray.length()>0)
                                 {
                                    for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)                                   
                                   {                                       
                                   JSONArray legs =jsonArray.getJSONArray("legs"); 
                                   if(legs.length()>0)
                                   {
                                    for(int i=0; i<legs.length(); i++)                                   
                                    {
                                    JSONObject object1 = legs.getJSONObject("distance");
                                    String distance = object1.getString("text");
                                   }
                               }
                           }
                       }
              }


                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
                    , new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                    ;
                    //  VolleyLog.d("", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                        Toast.makeText(ForgotPasswordActivity.this, "Timeout Error",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                        VolleyLog.d("", "" + error.getMessage() + "," + error.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            ) {
                @Override
                protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    params.put("user_email", email);

                    return params;
                }
            };
            sr.setShouldCache(true);

            sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(50000 * 2, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(sr);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```